# Android How to calculate network usage packet/data

Tags: java, android, android-intent, network-programming

Now a days Internet access is very costly.The provider used charges like hell.
We do not use unlimited plan for internet.That's why I would like to develop an that can facilities to calculate(manage) network package/data usage.

Suppose I have  activated 5GB data plan.So I need to check before surfing net,upload/download things.

I know some Data provider provides these facility .I want to capture network data packets on my android device by my app. But How can I do that into my own code.
Any help will be appreciated.
Thank you advance

Comment: Try this one : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/TrafficStats.html

Answer (score 5):

Please check that.

```
TextView infoView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.traffic_info);
String info = "";

info += "Mobile Interface:\n";
info += ("\tReceived: " + TrafficStats.getMobileRxBytes() + " bytes / " + TrafficStats.getMobileRxPackets() + " packets\n");
info += ("\tTransmitted: " + TrafficStats.getMobileTxBytes() + " bytes / " + TrafficStats.getMobileTxPackets() + " packets\n");

info += "All Network Interface:\n";
info += ("\tReceived: " + TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes() + " bytes / " + TrafficStats.getTotalRxPackets() + " packets\n");
info += ("\tTransmitted: " + TrafficStats.getTotalTxBytes() + " bytes / " + TrafficStats.getTotalTxPackets() + " packets\n");

infoView.setText(info);
```

Comment: When you use these methods to get the bytes and packets what date range does it use? The past week? Month? Forever?

Comment: It gets info since the last boot time. Every boot the counts reset to 0.

Answer (score 0):

Use TrafficStats class starting in APILevel 8.
You get overall usage per radio access technology and per app.

See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/TrafficStats.html
It's all static methods, for example call TrafficStats.getMobileRxBytes()

Comment: Thank you very much .Could you please share more details.like link some tutorials ...